# Inserting parts of a String in Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, return-value

I am currently learning Java in school and I am having a hard time with this one assignment.  What you are supposed to do is take a string and insert "like" in between every word to make it "teen talk" i.e. I like love like to like code.

```
public String teenTalk(String sentence)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
   {
       if(sentence.substring(i, i+1).equals(" "))
       {
           System.out.println("like");

       }
   }

   return sentence;

}
```

Does anyone know how I would insert "like" in a certain location, and how I could make it insert in the spaces that it is supposed to?  As you can see, I have also been having problems with making infinite loops.

Comment: Unless restricted, use String functions such as replace, replaceAll.

Comment: The thing about `String` in Java is it's immutable - you can't alter it.  You can only make a new `String`.  The reasons for this will become clearer the more you study the language.  In the meantime, you can build up new `String` instances with the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class.  You can also use the `+=` operator, which is really a wrapper around `StringBuilder` (at this point in the language's history.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What you are supposed to do is take a string and insert "like" in
>   between every word to make it "teen talk".

`strings` are immutable meaning each time you manipulate ( i.e `substring` method in your case) a particular `string` you'll get a new `string` back and the original `string` is **not** modified. Alternatively, you could either use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (mutable) or use the [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method.

using [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
public String teenTalk(String sentence){
     return sentence.replace(" ", " like ");
}
```

using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
public String teenTalk(String sentence) {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
           if(sentence.charAt(i) == ' '){
              builder.append(" like ");
           }else{
              builder.append(sentence.charAt(i));
           }
       }
       return builder.toString();
}
```

assuming this is the input:

```
System.out.println(teenTalk("teen talk"));
```

output:

```
teen like talk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "I love coding"; //Any string you wish
StringJoiner sj= new StringJoiner(" like "); //here,"like" is the Join you need between every word
Arrays.asList(text.split(" ")).forEach(word -> sj.add(word)); //we are splitting your text and adding each word. This will insert "like" after every addition except the last
System.out.println(sj.toString()); // Converting to String
```

Learn more about StringJoiner here https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stringjoiner-example/